# Automation Error Using Lotus database in VBA (Server threw an exception)

Tags: excel, lotus-notes, lotus, vba

I'm not an expert in VBA and Lotus but i understand code. But here, i'm really blocked : this macro worked 2 weeks ago, no no update from me and now i have this issue :

Executing error '-2147417851 (80010105)'
Automation Error
The server threw an exception

Here is my code :

```
Public Sub CleanGpmoAgenda()
Dim Session As Object
Dim Database As Object
Dim Doc As Object

Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.Notessession")
Set Database = Session.GETDATABASE("PARFMB104/SERVERS/GROUP", "mail\Mail3\PARITGGROCOO.nsf")

Dim Ligne As Integer
Ligne = 1

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro Utils")

    Do While .Cells(Ligne, 1) <> ""
         If CDate(.Cells(Ligne, 2)) >= DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now)) Then

            Set Doc = Database.GetDocumentByUnid(.Cells(Ligne, 1))
                Doc.Remove (True)

                .Cells(Ligne, 1) = ""
                .Cells(Ligne, 2) = ""

        End If
        Ligne = Ligne + 1
    Loop
End With

Set Session = Nothing
Set Database = Nothing
End Sub
```

The content of .Cells(Ligne, 1) is UnID of the documents
The content of .Cells(Ligne, 2) is date

The debug highlit the line "Set Doc = Database.GetDocumentByUnid(.Cells(Ligne, 1))" and i don't know why...

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Does the document with the UNID in the cell (Ligne,1) still exist in the database mail\Mail3\PARITGGROCOO.nsf?  And does the user who is running this macro have access to that database and to the document?

Comment: Thanks Richard, that was the problem ! The document was deleted by someone. I just eras the reference in cell(ligne, 1) and all works :)